# Prove that the following sequence has a finite partial limit

Tags: calculus, limits

> Let $ a_n $ be a sequence.
>
> Prove that if the sequence $|a_n| $ does not converge to $\infty$, $a_n$ has a finite partial limit.

Comment: What's a final number? What's a final partial limit?

Comment: a final number is a real number (non +- infinity), a final partial limit means that there is a subsequence that converges to a real number (non +- infinity)

Comment: it seems false.. if $a_0 = 1, a_n = 2a_{n-1}$, the sequence does not converge and does not have a final partial limit

Comment: @GitGud he means finite number.

Comment: @GinKin Ohhhhhh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $|a_n|$ doesn't converge there must be a subsequence $b_i$ such that $b_i \in [-K,K]$ for some $K \in \mathbb{R}$ (If such a subsequence doesn't exist $\text{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty}|a_n|=\infty$). Now take any convergent subsequence of $b_i$ (exists due to Bolzano Weierstrass).

Comment: is $b_i$ a subsequence of $a_n$ or $|a_n|$

Comment: $b_i$ is a subsequence of $a_n$